# What does dairy sensitivity feel like to an infant?

Tags: dairy

We have a 4-month-old, exclusively breast-fed, with dairy sensitivities. Mom has eliminated dairy from her diet, which brought a huge improvement. A couple weeks ago we slowly reintroduced dairy (a couple biscuits made with milk) and confirmed the sensitivity is still there.

Has there been any research on what the infant is actually experiencing? When she was younger, it seemed an almost acute pain - sitting happily one second then an utterly pained cry the next, refusal to be set down, etc. During the recent reintroduction it didn't seem to be as painful, but just a general discomfort - wanting to be held, but no pain cry.

The oddest thing though was the effect on sleep. Before the reintroduction she'd been sleeping through the night without issue. During, she would wake up 2-3 times per night. Upon waking she would lie there and babble, or work her hand out of the swaddle to suck on her fingers, and one time she just hollered (loud noises, but not unhappy). It just seemed like she was ready to be awake and play. We eventually just nursed her to get her to go back to sleep, but she never really got upset and "needed" to nurse.

Really I'm just curious what she might be going through, as I obviously don't have an intolerance and she can't tell me. Her changing reactions haven't helped me figure it out either.

Comment: How's she doing now?  Her symptoms seem contraindicative of a cow's–milk allergy, the symptoms of which are much like most other histamine attacks:  hives, flushing and redness, swelling, respiratory problems.  I hope you got some useful information during the 18 months since you asked.

Comment: Thanks for asking! You're right in that it never seemed like a full-blown allergy, just sensitivity. She's doing a lot better now. She can handle cheese, baked goods with milk, ice cream. Pretty much everything except a straight-up glass of milk. That's more due to us still taking it slow than anything - in the past there has seemed to be some correlation between having dairy and getting a stuffy nose. Every time we think about trying milk she gets the sniffles so we hold off. But she has handled everything else just fine. Never did figure out how it felt to her tho!